# SqlCommandProvider failing to call stored procedure with table-valued parameter

Tags: .net, t-sql, stored-procedures, f#, table-valued-parameters

I am using .NET framework 4.6.1 in a F# project. In earlier version, I could use a `SqlCommandProvider` which would call a stored procedure (which accepts a table-valued parameter). But recently it is showing an error:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>
> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[]' to type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlDataRecord'.
>
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__97`1.MoveNext()

The code has not been changed, just the .NET version or F# runtime version. I guess, the method cannot convert my table-value args to required SQL type. I have also tried `SqlProgrammabilityProvider` with no luck.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

It was multiple versions of `FSharp.Data.SqlClient`. One project was using 1.8.2 and a newer project of same solution was using 1.8.6. I forced both to be 1.8.2

But the error message is weird.

Comment: You might change the question to reflect the error instead of what you were trying to do, since the fact that it was a stored procedure with a table-valued parameter is not relevant